# How to add SEARCH BOX using XAML

Tags: xaml, search

I have to add a search box, which has dropdown button kind (say it wil have TeamBook and PersonalBook) then when i select TeamBook, the searchbox should get the default data as "SearchTeambook" if not,"SearchpersonalBook".

I have to do this using XAML.
Please help me in doing this.

Thanks
Ramm

Comment: I hav found out ways of solving this. 

Thank You
Ramm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the better way of solvingthis .
Now i am able to use the feature

Thanks
Ramm